# Cannot pass context between two classes [kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I am new to Kotlin.
I have two classes `LoginActivity` and `DashboardActivity`.
In the `DashboardActivity` I have a method:

```
fun createActivity(context: Context){
        val intent = Intent(context, DashboardActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

and in the `LoginActivity`, when the user clicks the button to login, I have a method that calls the previous method:

```
private fun onClickLogin() {
        val username : String = editTextUsername.text.toString()
        val password : String = editTextPassword.text.toString()

        if (username.isEmpty()){
            editTextUsername.error = "Insira um username"
            return
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()){
            editTextPassword.error = "Insira uma password"
            return
        }

       if (username.compareTo("user") == 0 && password.compareTo("password") == 0){
           DashboardActivity().createActivity(this)
       }
}
```

The problem is, every time I try to call **DashboardActivity().createActivity(this)**, I get a **NullPointerException**.
Here is the logcat:

[Click here, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cKb3.png)

So, why do I get this error? Is it because I cannot pass the context like this?
I have tried using `this@LoginActivity` but didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that:
 `DashboardActivity().createActivity(this)`
in that line you are trying to initialize activity and then use a method.

What you should do is:

1.

```
startActivity(DashboardActivity.createActivity(this))
```

2.
 In `DashboardActivity.kt`

```
companion object {
      fun createActivity(context: Context): Intent {
        return Intent(context, DashboardActivity::class.java)
      }
}
```

This creates `createActivity` method as "static" which means that you can access without need to initilize an intsance of this class.

Comment: Thanks! One thing tho, inside the companion object, the "startActivity(intent)" gives me an error... Why?

Comment: correct, you should't put it inside createActivity(), I will edit my post.
inside Dashboard Activity you should return Intent which will be used inside the LoginActivity and you use this intent to startActivity

Comment: Hm, and why can't I put it inside createActivity()? What is the reason?

Comment: as mentioned it is inside companion object -> static. And startActivity can be only used on objects.

Answer (score 0):

> every time I try to call DashboardActivity().createActivity(this), I get a NullPointerException

Never create an instance of an activity class yourself.

> why do I get this error?

Because you created an instance of `DashboardActivity` yourself and tried using it.

> I have tried using this@LoginActivity but didn't work...

Make `createActivity()` be [a function on a `companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). This will require a slight change to your implementation, calling `startActivity()` on the passed-in `Context`.

Comment: Why should I never create an instance of an activity class?

Comment: @AndréSilva: Only the framework code can create an activity correctly. Your `DashboardActivity()` instance is going to be fairly broken, for any functionality that it inherits from `Activity` or `Context`.

Comment: So the companion objects are always used when I want to access other classes methods?

Comment: @AndréSilva: A companion object in Kotlin is akin to `static` methods in Java. Companion objects provide functions that are global in scope -- if `createActivity()` is a function on a companion object on `DashboardActivity`, you do not need an instance of `DashboardActivity`. As I noted just now in an update to the answer, since there is no `DashboardActivity` instance, you would call `startActivity()` on the passed-in `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

use ApplicationContext

```
fun createActivity(){
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, DashboardActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```